# Is htmlview too elementar?

Tags: java, android, html

This is certainly a very basic question, please excuse me if this is well known.

I made a Java app that generates a HTML file 'fileout' to be viewed locally (essentially a page with thumbnails that open bigger images with some javascript (not really needed); both thumbnails and images are in my sdcard). Then my app calls an intent to open the page, in the usual way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileout), "text/html");
startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is that the app calls HtmlView, that behaves too restrictive: no back action to open another image, horrible title bar (I want full screen), not really good rendering of thumbnails, etc. So my question is:

Is there a way to configure Htmlview? How configurable is it? Does it understand javascript?

Moreover, if you think I would be better served with the default browser, how do I tell the app to open the browser instead of htmlview?

Sorry for the several-in-one questions, but they are all linked.

Thanks!

L.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `WebView` rather than HtmlView? While `WebView` is fairly configurable and you could make it into a reasonable browser experience, it's a bit of work to do so. `WebView` does support JavaScript, but you have to [enable it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled%28boolean%29). As for "not really good rendering of thumbnails", that's rather vague. All in all, unless you have some specific need to run it in your own view, I would tend to prefer to just open the file in a browser if that experience is acceptable. Your current code should actually already do so... Perhaps the app selector popped up and you set it to use your app by default?

Comment: My intent just opens the page with Htmlview on the title bar, so that's why I think it is Htmlview. The thumbnails appear unevenly distributed. How do I open the page in a web browser from inside my app?

Comment: It sounds like you just have some `Activity` called HtmlView.

Comment: No, the code posted in the original post (intent) opens what it decides to. I have no mention to any htmlview.

Comment: Then it seems you have another app on your device with an activity titled HtmlView that is set to handle web pages by default.

Comment: HtmlView is an app that is loaded on some devices used for viewing local html files, as the stock browser is (unfortunately) not able to open local files.

Comment: Actually, my stock browser does open local files, if you put in the address "file://<fullpath>". However, I don't know how to call it from my app - yes, quite a newbie question. :o)

Comment: Well, I got an answer to one of my questions. To open the local html file into the stock browser, just add the following line between the first and second lines of my original code: intent.setClassName("com.android.browser","com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");

Comment: One problem with "com.android.browser" is that it complains that there is "No network connection". Works, but the popup is annoying. :o(

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebView that will load html file you want and js hand by hand. This will allow you  not to leave your activity or application at all.

WebView can be configured as you want it.

Idea:
Start new activity that will run with no title bar/windows fullscreen.
Read: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html
for setting different window flags.

In your activity set content view to some WebView

Read:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html
Pay attention on `.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: Indeed, that's a possibility, to 'create' my custom browser... There should be a tutorial somewhere.